# Java AbstractTableModel: getValueAt does not use updated data

Tags: java, swing, abstracttablemodel

I have a Java application with four card panels. In the first panel, I receive data for the first geographic point, in the second and third -- for the other two points, and in the fourth panel, I have a JTable that displays extracted information about these three points.

The following code can be used to compile the application. On each Card panel, try to click the button next to the JTextfield to add the data.

**Package models**

Class AppSingleton

```
public class AppSingleton 
{
  private static AppSingleton instance = null;  

  public List<List<String>> flightPlanShared = new ArrayList<List<String>>(){{
    add(Arrays.asList(""));
    add(Arrays.asList(""));
    add(Arrays.asList(""));
  }};

  private AppSingleton() 
  {

  }

  public static AppSingleton getInstance() 
  {
    if(instance == null) 
    {
        instance = new AppSingleton();
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Class Model_Flightplan

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import presenters.Presenter;
import views.View_MainFrame;

public class Model_Flightplan 
{
    AppSingleton appSingleton = AppSingleton.getInstance( );
    private Presenter presenter;
    private View_MainFrame viewMainFrame; 

    public Model_Flightplan(View_MainFrame viewMainFrame) 
    {
       this.viewMainFrame = viewMainFrame;
    }

    public Presenter getPresenter() {
        return presenter;
    }

    public void setPresenter(Presenter presenter) {
       this.presenter = presenter;
    }

    public void addDepartureAirport() 
    {          
      List<String> component = new ArrayList<>();
      component.add("KLAS");
      component.add("KLAS");
      component.add("KLAS");

      appSingleton.flightPlanShared.set(0, component);
    }                                         

    public void addDestinationAirport()
    {
      List<String> component = new ArrayList<>();
      component.add("KLAX");
      component.add("KLAX");
      component.add("KLAX");

      appSingleton.flightPlanShared.set( (appSingleton.flightPlanShared.size() - 2), component);
    }

    public void addAlternateAirport()
    {
      List<String> component = new ArrayList<>();
      component.add("KSEA");
      component.add("KSEA");
      component.add("KSEA");

      appSingleton.flightPlanShared.set( (appSingleton.flightPlanShared.size() - 1), component);
     }  
 }
```

Class Model_TableWindsAloft

```
package models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Model_TableWindsAloft extends AbstractTableModel
{

    String[] columnNames = {"ICAO","Name","Type"};

    private List<List<String>> tableData = new ArrayList<>();

    public Model_TableWindsAloft(List<List<String>> tableData)
    {
       this.tableData = tableData;
       System.out.println("CONSTRUCTOR? "+tableData);
    }


    @Override
    public int getRowCount() 
    {
        System.out.println("DATA COUNT? "+tableData.size());
       return(tableData.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
       return(columnNames.length);
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) 
    {
       return columnNames[column] ;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) 
    {
      System.out.println("WHAT IS DATA 1? "+tableData);

      List<String> data = tableData.get(rowIndex);

      System.out.println("WHAT IS DATA 2? "+data);

      if(data.size()>=3)
      {
        switch(columnIndex) 
        {
            case 0: 
                return data.get(0);
            case 1:
                return data.get(1);
            case 2:
                return data.get(2);
            default: 
                return null;
         }
       }
       else
       {
          return null;
       }
    }
 }
```

**Package presenters**

Class Presenter

```
package presenters;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import models.Model_Flightplan;
import views.View_MainFrame;

public class Presenter 
{
  private final View_MainFrame viewMainFrame;
  private final Model_Flightplan model;

  public Presenter(View_MainFrame viewMainFrame, Model_Flightplan model) 
  {
    this.viewMainFrame = viewMainFrame;
    this.model = model;
  }

  public void displayTabDep() 
  {            
    CardLayout card = (CardLayout)viewMainFrame.getPanelContext().getLayout();
    card.show(viewMainFrame.getPanelContext(), "cardDep");
    viewMainFrame.addButtonsFlightplan();
    viewMainFrame.btnPnlDeparture.setEnabled(false);
  }

  public void displayTabDest() 
  {
    CardLayout card = (CardLayout)viewMainFrame.getPanelContext().getLayout();
    card.show(viewMainFrame.getPanelContext(), "cardDest");
    viewMainFrame.addButtonsFlightplan();
    viewMainFrame.btnPnlDestination.setEnabled(false);
  }

  public void displayTabAlt() 
  {
    CardLayout card = (CardLayout)viewMainFrame.getPanelContext().getLayout();
    card.show(viewMainFrame.getPanelContext(), "cardAlt");
    viewMainFrame.addButtonsFlightplan();
    viewMainFrame.btnPnlAlternate.setEnabled(false);
  }

  public void displayTabWindsAloft() 
  {
    CardLayout card = (CardLayout)viewMainFrame.getPanelContext().getLayout();
    card.show(viewMainFrame.getPanelContext(), "cardWindsAloft");

    viewMainFrame.addButtonsFlightplan();
    viewMainFrame.btnPnlWindsAloft.setEnabled(false);

    viewMainFrame.createPanelWindsAloft();
  }

  public void addDeparture()
  {
    model.addDepartureAirport();
  }

  public void addDestination()
  {
    model.addDestinationAirport();
  }

  public void addAlternate()
  {
    model.addAlternateAirport();
  }
}
```

**Package views**

Class View_MainFrame

```
package views;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import models.AppSingleton;
import presenters.Presenter;

public class View_MainFrame 
{
  AppSingleton appSingleton = AppSingleton.getInstance( );
  private Presenter presenter;
  private JPanel panelContext;

  private JFrame frame;

  public JPanel pnlDep;
  public JPanel pnlDest;
  public JPanel pnlAlt;
  public JPanel pnlWindsAloft;
  public JPanel panelButtons;
  public JButton btnFlightplan;
  public JPanel panelButtonsAdd;
  public JButton btnFlightplanDummy;
  public JPanel pnlDepAirport;
  private JButton btnAddDep;

  private javax.swing.JPanel pnlDestAirport;
  public JButton btnAddDest;

  private javax.swing.JPanel pnlAltAirport;
  public JButton btnAddAlt;

  private javax.swing.JPanel pnlWindsAloftInfo;
  private javax.swing.JPanel pnlWindsAloftTable;
  public JButton btnPnlDeparture;
  public JButton btnPnlDestination;
  public JButton btnPnlAlternate;
  public JButton btnPnlWindsAloft;

  public View_MainFrame()
  {
    createUI();
  }

  private void createUI() 
  {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    frame = new JFrame("iGoDispatch IXEG Boeing-733");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    Dimension frameSize = new Dimension(1050,700);
    Dimension frameSizeMin = new Dimension(500,200);
    frame.setPreferredSize(frameSize);
    frame.setMinimumSize(frameSizeMin);

    createPanelButtons();
    createPanelButtonsAdd();
    createPanelDeparture();
    createPanelDestination();
    createPanelAlternate();
    pnlWindsAloft = new JPanel();
    pnlWindsAloft.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
    createPanelWindsAloft();

    setPanelContext(new JPanel());
    getPanelContext().setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(getPanelContext(), java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    getPanelContext().add(pnlDep, "cardDep");
    getPanelContext().add(pnlDest, "cardDest");
    getPanelContext().add(pnlAlt, "cardAlt");
    getPanelContext().add(pnlWindsAloft, "cardWindsAloft");

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  }

  public JPanel getPanelContext() {
    return panelContext;
  }

  public void setPanelContext(JPanel panelContext) {
    this.panelContext = panelContext;
  }

  private void createPanelButtons()
  {
    panelButtons = new JPanel();
    panelButtons.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
    panelButtons.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 0));
    Dimension panelButtonsMinSize = new Dimension(1050,60);
    panelButtons.setMinimumSize(panelButtonsMinSize);

    btnFlightplan = new JButton();
    btnFlightplan.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 1, 13)); // NOI18N
    btnFlightplan.setText("Flightplan");
    btnFlightplan.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    btnFlightplan.setIconTextGap(5);
    btnFlightplan.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(70, 70));
    btnFlightplan.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(70, 70));
    btnFlightplan.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(70, 70));
    btnFlightplan.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    btnFlightplan.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> 
    {
        getPresenter().displayTabDep();
    });
    panelButtons.add(btnFlightplan);

    frame.getContentPane().add(panelButtons, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
  }

  private void createPanelButtonsAdd()
  {
    panelButtonsAdd = new JPanel();
    panelButtonsAdd.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    frame.getContentPane().add(panelButtonsAdd, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panelButtonsAdd.setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout(java.awt.FlowLayout.LEFT));

    // Dummy button
    btnFlightplanDummy = new JButton();
    btnFlightplanDummy.setAlignmentY(0.0F);
    btnFlightplanDummy.setEnabled(false);
    btnFlightplanDummy.setVisible(false);
    btnFlightplanDummy.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    btnFlightplanDummy.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    btnFlightplanDummy.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    panelButtonsAdd.add(btnFlightplanDummy);

    addButtonsFlightplan();
  }

  public void addButtonsFlightplan()
  {
    removeButtons();
    Dimension buttonDim = new Dimension(50, 50);
    Font buttonFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 10);
    btnPnlDeparture = new JButton("DEP");
    btnPnlDeparture.setPreferredSize(buttonDim);
    btnPnlDeparture.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnPnlDeparture.setVisible(true);
    btnPnlDeparture.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> 
    {
        getPresenter().displayTabDep();
    }); 

    panelButtonsAdd.add(btnPnlDeparture);

    btnPnlDestination = new JButton("ARR");
    btnPnlDestination.setPreferredSize(buttonDim);
    btnPnlDestination.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnPnlDestination.setVisible(true);
    btnPnlDestination.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> 
    {
        getPresenter().displayTabDest();
    });
    panelButtonsAdd.add(btnPnlDestination);

    btnPnlAlternate = new JButton("ALT");
    btnPnlAlternate.setPreferredSize(buttonDim);
    btnPnlAlternate.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnPnlAlternate.setVisible(true);
    btnPnlAlternate.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> 
    {
        getPresenter().displayTabAlt();
    });
    panelButtonsAdd.add(btnPnlAlternate);

    btnPnlWindsAloft = new JButton("WINDS");
    btnPnlWindsAloft.setPreferredSize(buttonDim);
    btnPnlWindsAloft.setFont(buttonFont);
    btnPnlWindsAloft.setVisible(true);
    btnPnlWindsAloft.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> 
    {
        getPresenter().displayTabWindsAloft();
    });
    panelButtonsAdd.add(btnPnlWindsAloft);

    panelButtonsAdd.revalidate();
    panelButtonsAdd.repaint();
  }


  private void removeButtons()
  {
    panelButtonsAdd.removeAll();
    panelButtonsAdd.revalidate();
    panelButtonsAdd.repaint();
  }

  private void createPanelDeparture()
  {
    java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

    pnlDep = new JPanel();
    pnlDep.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    pnlDepAirport = new JPanel();
    pnlDepAirport.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    btnAddDep = new JButton();
    btnAddDep.setText("ADD");
    btnAddDep.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(35, 35));
    btnAddDep.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(35, 35));
    btnAddDep.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(35, 35));
    btnAddDep.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> 
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame(); 
        JDialog modalDialog = new JDialog(f, "Busy", Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
        modalDialog.setSize(200, 100);
        modalDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(f);
        modalDialog.setUndecorated(true);
        // Remove menu buttons
        modalDialog.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
        modalDialog.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.WHITE );
        // Add rotating activity indicator
        ImageIcon loading = new ImageIcon("src/images/activityIndicator.gif");
        modalDialog.add(new JLabel("Please wait... ", loading, JLabel.CENTER));
        // Set activity indicator visible
        modalDialog.setVisible(true);

        new Thread(() ->
        {
            getPresenter().addDeparture(); 
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
            {
                modalDialog.setVisible(false);
                modalDialog.dispose();
            });
        }).start();
    });
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(5, 15, 5, 5);
    pnlDepAirport.add(btnAddDep, gridBagConstraints);

    pnlDep.add(pnlDepAirport);
  }

  private void createPanelDestination()
  {
    java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

    pnlDest = new JPanel();
    pnlDest.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    pnlDestAirport = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    pnlDestAirport.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    btnAddDest = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnAddDest.setText("jButton1");
    btnAddDest.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(35, 35));
    btnAddDest.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(35, 35));
    btnAddDest.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(35, 35));
    btnAddDest.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> 
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame(); 
        JDialog modalDialog = new JDialog(f, "Busy", Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
        modalDialog.setSize(200, 100);
        modalDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(f);
        modalDialog.setUndecorated(true);
        // Remove menu buttons
        modalDialog.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
        modalDialog.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.WHITE );
        // Add rotating activity indicator
        ImageIcon loading = new ImageIcon("src/images/activityIndicator.gif");
        modalDialog.add(new JLabel("Please wait... ", loading, JLabel.CENTER));
        // Set activity indicator visible
        modalDialog.setVisible(true);

        new Thread(() ->
        {
            getPresenter().addDestination(); 
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
            {
                //displayValues();

                modalDialog.setVisible(false);
                modalDialog.dispose();

            });
        }).start();
    });
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(5, 15, 5, 5);
    pnlDestAirport.add(btnAddDest, gridBagConstraints);

    pnlDest.add(pnlDestAirport);
  }

  private void createPanelAlternate()
  {
    java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

    pnlAlt = new JPanel();
    pnlAlt.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    pnlAltAirport = new JPanel();
    pnlAltAirport.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    btnAddAlt = new JButton();
    btnAddAlt.setText("ADD");
    btnAddAlt.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(35, 35));
    btnAddAlt.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(35, 35));
    btnAddAlt.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(35, 35));
    btnAddAlt.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> 
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame(); 
        JDialog modalDialog = new JDialog(f, "Busy", Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
        modalDialog.setSize(200, 100);
        modalDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(f);
        modalDialog.setUndecorated(true);
        // Remove menu buttons
        modalDialog.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
        modalDialog.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.WHITE );
        // Add rotating activity indicator
        ImageIcon loading = new ImageIcon("src/images/activityIndicator.gif");
        modalDialog.add(new JLabel("Please wait... ", loading, JLabel.CENTER));
        // Set activity indicator visible
        modalDialog.setVisible(true);

        new Thread(() ->
        {
            getPresenter().addAlternate(); 
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
            {
                modalDialog.setVisible(false);
                modalDialog.dispose();
            });
        }).start();
    });
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(5, 15, 5, 5);
    pnlAltAirport.add(btnAddAlt, gridBagConstraints);

    pnlAlt.add(pnlAltAirport);
  }

  public void createPanelWindsAloft()
  {
    pnlWindsAloftInfo = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    pnlWindsAloftInfo.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 0));

    pnlWindsAloftTable = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    pnlWindsAloftTable.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    javax.swing.JTable tblWindsAloft = new javax.swing.JTable(new Model_TableWindsAloft(createDataForWindsTable()));

    JScrollPane scrollWindsAloft = new JScrollPane(tblWindsAloft,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    tblWindsAloft.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    tblWindsAloft.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    pnlWindsAloftTable.add(scrollWindsAloft, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

    pnlWindsAloftInfo.add(pnlWindsAloftTable);
    pnlWindsAloft.add(pnlWindsAloftInfo, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }

  public List<List<String>> createDataForWindsTable()
  {
    List<List<String>> finalResult = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("SIZE: "+finalResult.size());

    for (int i=0; i<appSingleton.flightPlanShared.size(); i++)
    {    
        String icao;
        String name;
        String type;

        if(appSingleton.flightPlanShared.get(i).size()>2)
        {
            icao = appSingleton.flightPlanShared.get(i).get(2);
            name = appSingleton.flightPlanShared.get(i).get(1);
            type = appSingleton.flightPlanShared.get(i).get(0);
        }
        else
        {
            icao = "";
            name = "";
            type = "";
        }

            List<String> components = new ArrayList<>();

            components.add(icao);
            components.add(name);
            components.add(type);

            System.out.println("COMPONENTS: "+components);

            finalResult.add(components);
    }

    /* THIS WORKS!
    String a1 = "LAS VEGAS/MC CARRAN ";
    String a2 = "KLAS";
    String a3 = "PORTDEP";

    List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
    a.add(a1);
    a.add(a2);
    a.add(a3);

    String b1 = "LOS ANGELES INTL";
    String b2 = "KLAX";
    String b3 = "PORTDEST";
    List<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
    b.add(b1);
    b.add(b2);
    b.add(b3);

    String c1 = "SEATTLE-TACOMA INTL";
    String c2 = "KSEA";
    String c3 = "PORTALT";
    List<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
    c.add(c1);
    c.add(c2);
    c.add(c3);

    finalResult.add(a);
    finalResult.add(b);
    finalResult.add(c);
    */

    System.out.println("DATA CREATED: "+finalResult);

    return finalResult;
  }

  public Presenter getPresenter() {
    return presenter;
  }

  public void setPresenter(Presenter presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;
  }
}
```

Main

```
package testjtable;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import models.Model_Flightplan;
import presenters.Presenter;
import views.View_MainFrame;

public class TestJTable {

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> 
    {
        View_MainFrame viewMainFrame = new View_MainFrame();
        viewMainFrame.setPresenter(new Presenter(viewMainFrame, new Model_Flightplan(viewMainFrame)));
    });
  }
}
```

Data does not appear inside the table unless (!!!) I click outside of the application.

EDIT:

I solved the problem by updating the model using the setValueAt() method:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) 
{
    setTableData(appSingleton.flightPlanShared);
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);     
}
```

Comment: For best help, please consider creating a small [mcve] out of this code and posting it with your question.

Comment: OK, I edited the original question to include code that can be used to compile a small sample application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be creating a new JTable and a new JPanel that holds it, with each press of the create winds aloft button.

Here is your btnPnlWindsAloft JButton's ActionListener:

```
btnPnlWindsAloft.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
    getPresenter().displayTabWindsAloft();
});
```

Notice that it calls `getPresenter().displayTabWindsAloft();` which is:

```
public void displayTabWindsAloft() {
    CardLayout card = (CardLayout) viewMainFrame.getPanelContext().getLayout();
    card.show(viewMainFrame.getPanelContext(), "cardWindsAloft");

    viewMainFrame.addButtonsFlightplan();
    viewMainFrame.btnPnlWindsAloft.setEnabled(false);

    viewMainFrame.createPanelWindsAloft();
}
```

And notice that this method calls `viewMainFrame.createPanelWindsAloft();` which is:

```
public void createPanelWindsAloft() {
    pnlWindsAloftInfo = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    pnlWindsAloftInfo.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 0));

    pnlWindsAloftTable = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    pnlWindsAloftTable.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    javax.swing.JTable tblWindsAloft = new javax.swing.JTable(
            new Model_TableWindsAloft(createDataForWindsTable()));

    JScrollPane scrollWindsAloft = new JScrollPane(tblWindsAloft,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    tblWindsAloft.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    tblWindsAloft.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    pnlWindsAloftTable.add(scrollWindsAloft, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pnlWindsAloftInfo.add(pnlWindsAloftTable);
    pnlWindsAloft.add(pnlWindsAloftInfo, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

... and every time this method is called, it  creates a new pnlWindsAloftInfo JPanel, a new pnlWindsAloftTable JPanel, a new tblWindsAloft JTable which it fills with a new table model, via a call to `createDataForWindsTable()`. Again, why are you re-creating these components and models unnecessarily?

Don't do this -- create your key components just once, and then while the program is running, change the state of the JTable's model as well as the state of the visibility of the "card" JPanel that holds the JTable, but don't keep re-creating JTables and models, some of which hold data, and some that don't.

Also the complexity of your program is needlessly huge, and this is likely preventing you from seeing the problem -- refactor and simply ***everything***.

Side issue: you are setting sizes of key components almost guaranteeing that they will not display appropriately on most systems (such as my system where the button text is displaying as `...`). You'll want to avoid this as well.

---

My current MCVE of your code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TestJTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            View_MainFrame viewMainFrame = new View_MainFrame();
            viewMainFrame.setPresenter(
                    new Presenter(viewMainFrame, new Model_Flightplan(viewMainFrame)));
        });
    }
}

class View_MainFrame {
    AppSingleton appSingleton = AppSingleton.getInstance();
    private Presenter presenter;
    private JPanel panelContext;

    private JFrame frame;

    public JPanel pnlDep;
    public JPanel pnlDest;
    public JPanel pnlAlt;
    public JPanel pnlWindsAloft;
    public JPanel panelButtons;
    public JButton btnFlightplan;
    public JPanel panelButtonsAdd;
    public JButton btnFlightplanDummy;
    public JPanel pnlDepAirport;
    private JButton btnAddDep;

    private javax.swing.JPanel pnlDestAirport;
    public JButton btnAddDest;

    private javax.swing.JPanel pnlAltAirport;
    public JButton btnAddAlt;

    private javax.swing.JPanel pnlWindsAloftInfo;
    private javax.swing.JPanel pnlWindsAloftTable;
    public JButton btnPnlDeparture;
    public JButton btnPnlDestination;
    public JButton btnPnlAlternate;
    public JButton btnPnlWindsAloft;

    public View_MainFrame() {
        createUI();
    }

    private void createUI() {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        frame = new JFrame("iGoDispatch IXEG Boeing-733");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(
                new javax.swing.BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        Dimension frameSize = new Dimension(1050, 700);
        Dimension frameSizeMin = new Dimension(500, 200);
        frame.setPreferredSize(frameSize);
        frame.setMinimumSize(frameSizeMin);

        createPanelButtons();
        createPanelButtonsAdd();
        createPanelDeparture();
        createPanelDestination();
        createPanelAlternate();
        pnlWindsAloft = new JPanel();
        pnlWindsAloft.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
        createPanelWindsAloft();

        setPanelContext(new JPanel());
        getPanelContext().setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(getPanelContext(), java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        getPanelContext().add(pnlDep, "cardDep");
        getPanelContext().add(pnlDest, "cardDest");
        getPanelContext().add(pnlAlt, "cardAlt");
        getPanelContext().add(pnlWindsAloft, "cardWindsAloft");

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public JPanel getPanelContext() {
        return panelContext;
    }

    public void setPanelContext(JPanel panelContext) {
        this.panelContext = panelContext;
    }

    private void createPanelButtons() {
        panelButtons = new JPanel();
        panelButtons.setBorder(
                new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        panelButtons.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 0));
        Dimension panelButtonsMinSize = new Dimension(1050, 60);
        panelButtons.setMinimumSize(panelButtonsMinSize);

        btnFlightplan = new JButton();
        btnFlightplan.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 1, 13));
        btnFlightplan.setText("Flightplan");
        btnFlightplan.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        btnFlightplan.setIconTextGap(5);
        btnFlightplan.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(90, 70));
        btnFlightplan.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(90, 70));
        btnFlightplan.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(90, 70));
        btnFlightplan.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        btnFlightplan.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> {
            getPresenter().displayTabDep();
        });
        panelButtons.add(btnFlightplan);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panelButtons, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    private void createPanelButtonsAdd() {
        panelButtonsAdd = new JPanel();
        panelButtonsAdd.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        frame.getContentPane().add(panelButtonsAdd, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panelButtonsAdd.setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout(java.awt.FlowLayout.LEFT));
        btnFlightplanDummy = new JButton();
        btnFlightplanDummy.setAlignmentY(0.0F);
        btnFlightplanDummy.setEnabled(false);
        btnFlightplanDummy.setVisible(false);
        btnFlightplanDummy.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
        btnFlightplanDummy.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
        btnFlightplanDummy.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
        panelButtonsAdd.add(btnFlightplanDummy);

        addButtonsFlightplan();
    }

    public void addButtonsFlightplan() {
        removeButtons();
        Dimension buttonDim = new Dimension(150, 50);
        Font buttonFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 10);
        btnPnlDeparture = new JButton("DEP");
        btnPnlDeparture.setPreferredSize(buttonDim);
        btnPnlDeparture.setFont(buttonFont);
        btnPnlDeparture.setVisible(true);
        btnPnlDeparture.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            getPresenter().displayTabDep();
        });

        panelButtonsAdd.add(btnPnlDeparture);

        btnPnlDestination = new JButton("ARR");
        btnPnlDestination.setPreferredSize(buttonDim);
        btnPnlDestination.setFont(buttonFont);
        btnPnlDestination.setVisible(true);
        btnPnlDestination.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            getPresenter().displayTabDest();
        });
        panelButtonsAdd.add(btnPnlDestination);

        btnPnlAlternate = new JButton("ALT");
        btnPnlAlternate.setPreferredSize(buttonDim);
        btnPnlAlternate.setFont(buttonFont);
        btnPnlAlternate.setVisible(true);
        btnPnlAlternate.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            getPresenter().displayTabAlt();
        });
        panelButtonsAdd.add(btnPnlAlternate);

        btnPnlWindsAloft = new JButton("WINDS");
        btnPnlWindsAloft.setPreferredSize(buttonDim);
        btnPnlWindsAloft.setFont(buttonFont);
        btnPnlWindsAloft.setVisible(true);
        btnPnlWindsAloft.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            getPresenter().displayTabWindsAloft();
        });
        panelButtonsAdd.add(btnPnlWindsAloft);

        panelButtonsAdd.revalidate();
        panelButtonsAdd.repaint();
    }

    private void removeButtons() {
        panelButtonsAdd.removeAll();
        panelButtonsAdd.revalidate();
        panelButtonsAdd.repaint();
    }

    private void createPanelDeparture() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        pnlDep = new JPanel();
        pnlDep.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        pnlDepAirport = new JPanel();
        pnlDepAirport.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        btnAddDep = new JButton();
        btnAddDep.setText("ADD");
        btnAddDep.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(75, 35));
        btnAddDep.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(75, 35));
        btnAddDep.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(75, 35));
        btnAddDep.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            JDialog modalDialog = new JDialog(f, "Busy", Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
            modalDialog.setSize(200, 100);
            modalDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(f);
            modalDialog.setUndecorated(true);
            modalDialog.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
            modalDialog.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            modalDialog.add(new JLabel("Please wait... ", JLabel.CENTER));
            modalDialog.setVisible(true);

            new Thread(() -> {
                getPresenter().addDeparture();
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                    modalDialog.setVisible(false);
                    modalDialog.dispose();
                });
            }).start();
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(5, 15, 5, 5);
        pnlDepAirport.add(btnAddDep, gridBagConstraints);

        pnlDep.add(pnlDepAirport);
    }

    private void createPanelDestination() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        pnlDest = new JPanel();
        pnlDest.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        pnlDestAirport = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        pnlDestAirport.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        btnAddDest = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnAddDest.setText("jButton1");
        btnAddDest.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(75, 35));
        btnAddDest.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(75, 35));
        btnAddDest.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(75, 35));
        btnAddDest.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            JDialog modalDialog = new JDialog(f, "Busy", Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
            modalDialog.setSize(200, 100);
            modalDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(f);
            modalDialog.setUndecorated(true);
            modalDialog.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
            modalDialog.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            modalDialog.add(new JLabel("Please wait... ", JLabel.CENTER));
            modalDialog.setVisible(true);

            new Thread(() -> {
                getPresenter().addDestination();
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

                    modalDialog.setVisible(false);
                    modalDialog.dispose();

                });
            }).start();
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(5, 15, 5, 5);
        pnlDestAirport.add(btnAddDest, gridBagConstraints);

        pnlDest.add(pnlDestAirport);
    }

    private void createPanelAlternate() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        pnlAlt = new JPanel();
        pnlAlt.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        pnlAltAirport = new JPanel();
        pnlAltAirport.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        btnAddAlt = new JButton();
        btnAddAlt.setText("ADD");
        btnAddAlt.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(75, 35));
        btnAddAlt.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(75, 35));
        btnAddAlt.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(75, 35));
        btnAddAlt.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            JDialog modalDialog = new JDialog(f, "Busy", Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
            modalDialog.setSize(200, 100);
            modalDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(f);
            modalDialog.setUndecorated(true);
            modalDialog.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
            modalDialog.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            modalDialog.add(new JLabel("Please wait... ", JLabel.CENTER));
            modalDialog.setVisible(true);

            new Thread(() -> {
                getPresenter().addAlternate();
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                    modalDialog.setVisible(false);
                    modalDialog.dispose();
                });
            }).start();
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(5, 15, 5, 5);
        pnlAltAirport.add(btnAddAlt, gridBagConstraints);

        pnlAlt.add(pnlAltAirport);
    }

    public void createPanelWindsAloft() {
        pnlWindsAloftInfo = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        pnlWindsAloftInfo.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 0));

        pnlWindsAloftTable = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        pnlWindsAloftTable.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        javax.swing.JTable tblWindsAloft = new javax.swing.JTable(
                new Model_TableWindsAloft(createDataForWindsTable()));

        JScrollPane scrollWindsAloft = new JScrollPane(tblWindsAloft,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        tblWindsAloft.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        tblWindsAloft.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        pnlWindsAloftTable.add(scrollWindsAloft, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pnlWindsAloftInfo.add(pnlWindsAloftTable);
        pnlWindsAloft.add(pnlWindsAloftInfo, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public List<List<String>> createDataForWindsTable() {
        List<List<String>> finalResult = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("SIZE: " + finalResult.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < appSingleton.flightPlanShared.size(); i++) {
            String icao;
            String name;
            String type;

            if (appSingleton.flightPlanShared.get(i).size() > 2) {
                icao = appSingleton.flightPlanShared.get(i).get(2);
                name = appSingleton.flightPlanShared.get(i).get(1);
                type = appSingleton.flightPlanShared.get(i).get(0);
            } else {
                icao = "";
                name = "";
                type = "";
            }

            List<String> components = new ArrayList<>();

            components.add(icao);
            components.add(name);
            components.add(type);

            System.out.println("COMPONENTS: " + components);

            finalResult.add(components);
        }

        /*
         * THIS WORKS! String a1 = "LAS VEGAS/MC CARRAN "; String a2 = "KLAS";
         * String a3 = "PORTDEP";
         * 
         * List<String> a = new ArrayList<>(); a.add(a1); a.add(a2); a.add(a3);
         * 
         * String b1 = "LOS ANGELES INTL"; String b2 = "KLAX"; String b3 =
         * "PORTDEST"; List<String> b = new ArrayList<>(); b.add(b1); b.add(b2);
         * b.add(b3);
         * 
         * String c1 = "SEATTLE-TACOMA INTL"; String c2 = "KSEA"; String c3 =
         * "PORTALT"; List<String> c = new ArrayList<>(); c.add(c1); c.add(c2);
         * c.add(c3);
         * 
         * finalResult.add(a); finalResult.add(b); finalResult.add(c);
         */

        System.out.println("DATA CREATED: " + finalResult);

        return finalResult;
    }

    public Presenter getPresenter() {
        return presenter;
    }

    public void setPresenter(Presenter presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }
}

class Presenter {
    private final View_MainFrame viewMainFrame;
    private final Model_Flightplan model;

    public Presenter(View_MainFrame viewMainFrame, Model_Flightplan model) {
        this.viewMainFrame = viewMainFrame;
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void displayTabDep() {
        CardLayout card = (CardLayout) viewMainFrame.getPanelContext().getLayout();
        card.show(viewMainFrame.getPanelContext(), "cardDep");
        viewMainFrame.addButtonsFlightplan();
        viewMainFrame.btnPnlDeparture.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void displayTabDest() {
        CardLayout card = (CardLayout) viewMainFrame.getPanelContext().getLayout();
        card.show(viewMainFrame.getPanelContext(), "cardDest");
        viewMainFrame.addButtonsFlightplan();
        viewMainFrame.btnPnlDestination.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void displayTabAlt() {
        CardLayout card = (CardLayout) viewMainFrame.getPanelContext().getLayout();
        card.show(viewMainFrame.getPanelContext(), "cardAlt");
        viewMainFrame.addButtonsFlightplan();
        viewMainFrame.btnPnlAlternate.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void displayTabWindsAloft() {
        CardLayout card = (CardLayout) viewMainFrame.getPanelContext().getLayout();
        card.show(viewMainFrame.getPanelContext(), "cardWindsAloft");

        viewMainFrame.addButtonsFlightplan();
        viewMainFrame.btnPnlWindsAloft.setEnabled(false);

        viewMainFrame.createPanelWindsAloft();
    }

    public void addDeparture() {
        model.addDepartureAirport();
    }

    public void addDestination() {
        model.addDestinationAirport();
    }

    public void addAlternate() {
        model.addAlternateAirport();
    }
}

class Model_TableWindsAloft extends AbstractTableModel {

    String[] columnNames = { "ICAO", "Name", "Type" };

    private List<List<String>> tableData = new ArrayList<>();

    public Model_TableWindsAloft(List<List<String>> tableData) {
        this.tableData = tableData;
        System.out.println("CONSTRUCTOR? " + tableData);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        System.out.println("DATA COUNT? " + tableData.size());
        return (tableData.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return (columnNames.length);
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        System.out.println("WHAT IS DATA 1? " + tableData);

        List<String> data = tableData.get(rowIndex);

        System.out.println("WHAT IS DATA 2? " + data);

        if (data.size() >= 3) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return data.get(0);
            case 1:
                return data.get(1);
            case 2:
                return data.get(2);
            default:
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

class Model_Flightplan {
    AppSingleton appSingleton = AppSingleton.getInstance();
    private Presenter presenter;
    private View_MainFrame viewMainFrame;

    public Model_Flightplan(View_MainFrame viewMainFrame) {
        this.viewMainFrame = viewMainFrame;
    }

    public Presenter getPresenter() {
        return presenter;
    }

    public void setPresenter(Presenter presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }

    public void addDepartureAirport() {
        List<String> component = new ArrayList<>();
        component.add("KLAS");
        component.add("KLAS");
        component.add("KLAS");

        appSingleton.flightPlanShared.set(0, component);
    }

    public void addDestinationAirport() {
        List<String> component = new ArrayList<>();
        component.add("KLAX");
        component.add("KLAX");
        component.add("KLAX");

        appSingleton.flightPlanShared.set((appSingleton.flightPlanShared.size() - 2), component);
    }

    public void addAlternateAirport() {
        List<String> component = new ArrayList<>();
        component.add("KSEA");
        component.add("KSEA");
        component.add("KSEA");

        appSingleton.flightPlanShared.set((appSingleton.flightPlanShared.size() - 1), component);
    }
}

class AppSingleton {
    private static AppSingleton instance = null;

    public List<List<String>> flightPlanShared = new ArrayList<List<String>>() {
        {
            add(Arrays.asList(""));
            add(Arrays.asList(""));
            add(Arrays.asList(""));
        }
    };

    private AppSingleton() {

    }

    public static AppSingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AppSingleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! 1) I removed `viewMainFrame.createPanelWindsAloft();` from `displayTabWindsAloft()` in presenter. Now, the JTable is created only once. I also removed passing data from the Table Model constructor. 2) I added `viewMainFrame.tblWindsAloft.getModel().setValueAt("DEP", 0, 1);` in `addDeparture()` to update the table. The problem is still there, the table is not updated...

Comment: @IgorTupitsyn: please edit your question and post your latest [mcve] (see my post above to see the format of the code -- it should all be in one file -- and then comment back to me. Also please consider granting at least 1 up-vote for the efforts so far.

Comment: @IgorTupitsyn: and what is your currently displayed program adding to the JTable? I don't see it adding anything but empty data. Please explain.

Comment: @IgorTupitsyn??

Comment: Sorry, the week has been hectic here. I managed to solve the problem by using the setValueAt() method. I have edited my original question. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @IgorTupitsyn: thanks for getting back to me on this!